# Share users between two different DotNetNuke Installation

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, membership-provider

I have an existing application working on DNN 4.3. I am planning to write another application using DNN 6.2. I want to share user infromation between these two instances.
Is importing user data my only option or is there a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Almost surely using the [Datasprings Interactive User Import](http://www.datasprings.com/products/dnn-modules/interactive-user-import) tool will be the best option.  This option is preferred if you can get by with syncing either once, or at intervals larger than a week.

A second option is to verify that both web.configs have the same machinekey and to sync your user-authentication-system tables in a more manual fashion. I'm not sure if the user-authentication-system tables have changed between version 4.3 and version 6.2; I'd wager that they've changed a little and that you will have to build a manual syncing tool. DotNetNuke has its own UAC tables that ride in parallel to the standard ASP.NET UAC tables. Both will have to be synced if you go this route. This option will likely require a serious bit of research and development.

Answer (score 0):

Is this sort of thing that would be of use?
"Cross Portal Authentication: If a user attempts to login that belongs to another portal but not in the current portal then they are automatically registered to the current portal and logged in."

If so then see [OnyakTech LogIn](https://www.onyaktech.com/Products/tabid/65/CategoryID/0/List/1/catpagesize/0/Level/a/ProductID/18/Default.aspx?SortField=UnitCost%20DESC,ProductName).  It will take a bit of work to set up, however the developer provides good support.  Worth investigating to see if its of use.